# How can I use scope change event in services in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I Have a controller and a service. But now I want my controller code to be moved to services to make it reusable. But the problem I am facing here is my controller is using $scope service. That means my code is dependent on the $scope event. If I will move my code to service, how will I manage now this $scope event change in service.

Comment: If it's doing a lot of scope manupilation you should probably keep it as a controller. And what's more, noone ever said you can't reuse a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most effective way, but you can pass the $scope as a function parameter.

Controller:

```
MyService.aMethod($scope, otherParameter);
```

Service:

```
this.aMethod = function (scope, otherParameter) {
    scope.result = otherParameter * 10;
}
```